# x64 Application Accessing mdb database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, windows-7-x64

I have an application that needs to be built under x64 platform. I need to access an **.mdb** file. By accessing I mean, inserting, deleting or updating the db. I having trouble using Jet OLE db and ODBC drivers. With OLE db it shows "Jet Oledb not registered". With ODBC Platform mismatch between driver and application. I can do these operations in X86 platform. But in my application I was asked to build my project under x64 platform. Can anybody provide me with any solution. N.B. I should not use any 3rd application to communicate with x64 app and database.

Thanks to any response in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the newest driver from Microsoft called ACE
[Here you can find the download bits](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Pay attention to download the correct set (x64 or x86) for your intended target machine
Also the connection string should make use of these drivers, so you probably need a connection string like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=yourPathToTheMDBFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

As an alternative you could build your application for x86 platform and, if you don't have any direct interaction with 64bit code, it will works as is in the 64bit operating system. This solution is preferable because you could use the old JET.OleDb.4.0

Let me give a brief explanation of the problem with 64/32bit operating system, Platform used to build applications and 32/64bit drivers:

- **You build your application for AnyCPU platform**  - Your code works fine
  in 32/64 bit systems, the code emitted by the JIT compiler will have the
  same bitness of the guest OS. BUT, you could not use 32bit drivers by
  64bit apps and viceversa. JET.OleDB.4.0 is 32bit only. End of game if
  you compile for AnyCPU and run on 64bit. You need a 64bit driver.
- **You build your application for x86 platform** - Your code works fine in
  32/64 bit systems, and you can use 32bit drivers. Of course the code
  emitted by the JIT compiler is 32bit and thus you cannot use 64bit
  drivers on 64bit systems.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to uninstall my office 2007 (32 bit) Application

Comment: I don't understand you correctly then. The application will be deployed in another machine with a 64bit env or is your machine that has a 64bit env?

Comment: My machine is 64 bit but I am using 32 bit Office and I need to install accessengine_x64.exe. It fails to install. So problem occurs. But thanks that your solution works if I am using 64 bit office software or no 32 bit office installed in my pc.