# Connection between Ms Access2013 and windows form c# (oledb)

Tags: c#

i need help please ! 
i wanna have connection between microsoft acces 2013 and my windows form, it doesn't work i don't know why , that s my code :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source= C:\\Users\\NIZAR\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\C#\\testConnBD1\\testConnBD1\\madb1.accdb");
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error message you are getting?

Comment: Change your catch handler with `catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }` and tell us the error message displayed

Comment: My guess is the architecture being used needs to be set to x86: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879789/x64-application-accessing-mdb-database

Comment: thank's a lot Mr @Steve I get the error about the none found file in directory so i checked all the hierarchy i found that i make a mistake in the name of file really thanks a lot sir and all of you

Comment: Also I suggest taking the time to learn about the Entity Framework. It might seem like too much work to learn but it will save time later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1: 
It's Solved thank's all of you I made a mistake in the file's name :| 
EDIT2: The correct connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=@"C:\\Users\\%usename%\\{%pathToYourData%}\\{%databaseName.Extension%}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need the [`Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime.`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39358)

The Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime enables you to distribute Access 2013 applications to users who do not have the full version of Access 2013 installed on their computers.

Microsoft Access 2007 = ACE 12; Microsoft Access 2010 = ACE 14; Microsoft Access 2013 = ACE 15

[image]